# Nesting One or Multiple Forms in a Row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some simple HTML for a +/- Button, Phone Number Textbox, and a Phone Number Type Dropdown.

I'm new to Bootstrap, so with the help of the tool [Bootstrap Studio](https://bootstrapstudio.io/) I generated this code that I currently have:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-plus" type="button"></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-9">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="callerPhoneNumber" class="control-label">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="tel" name="callerPhoneNumber" required="" inputmode="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phoneNumberType" class="control-label">Label</label>
                <select name="phoneNumberType" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Mobile" selected="">Mobile</option>
                    <option value="Home">Home</option>
                    <option value="Work">Work</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's a single `row`, with three separate `div`s with `col-*` attributes for each item listed above. Within each of those is a single `form` and a single subsequent `form-group`

I've reduced this a bit by merging the `col-*` attributes with their respective `form-group` tags and moving all the `form-groups` into a single `form` tag.

```html
<div class="row">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3">
            <button class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-plus" type="button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-9">
            <label for="callerPhoneNumber" class="control-label">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="tel" name="callerPhoneNumber" required="" inputmode="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label for="phoneNumberType" class="control-label">Label</label>
            <select name="phoneNumberType" class="form-control">
                <option value="Mobile" selected="">Mobile</option>
                <option value="Home">Home</option>
                <option value="Work">Work</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

From a visual standpoint, they both seem to work the same.

Here's a snippet to show them (*I would suggest expanding it, doesn't look amazing small currently)*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  
    <!-- 1st Version -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-plus" type="button"></button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-9">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="callerPhoneNumber" class="control-label">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="tel" name="callerPhoneNumber" required="" inputmode="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phoneNumberType" class="control-label">Label</label>
            <select name="phoneNumberType" class="form-control">
              <option value="Mobile" selected="">Mobile</option>
              <option value="Home">Home</option>
              <option value="Work">Work</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- 2nd Version -->
    <div class="row">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3">
          <button class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-plus" type="button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-9">
          <label for="callerPhoneNumber" class="control-label">Phone Number</label>
          <input type="tel" name="callerPhoneNumber" required="" inputmode="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label for="phoneNumberType" class="control-label">Label</label>
          <select name="phoneNumberType" class="form-control">
            <option value="Mobile" selected="">Mobile</option>
            <option value="Home">Home</option>
            <option value="Work">Work</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
  </body>
</html>
```

**So what I'm wondering is:** if the 1st or 2nd version of this is better, or if both a fine. Perhaps there's a pitfall regarding these structures that I'm not aware of yet.